# how to match IPV4 regex pattern by excluding RFC1918 private addresses in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
import re
text='''10.11.0.0'''

pattern=re.compile(r'(\b(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5] 
{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\b)')

#pattern=re.compile(r'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b')
matches=pattern.finditer(text)

for match in matches:
  print(match.group())
```

This is the regex pattern for finding all the IPV4 addresses but I need to exclude RFC1918 adresses.Please provide the suggesstions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html), IP address regex is [`\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/SjC8GG/1).

You want to avoid matching IP addresses that start with `10`, `192.168` and a specific range of addresses that start with `172`.

Use

```
\b(?!10\.|192\.168\.|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vD8hkn/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!10\.|192\.168\.|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.)` - a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if RFC1918 addresses "markers" appear next:

  - `10\.` - `10.`
  - `192\.168\.` - `192.168.`
  - `172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.` - `172.`, then 16 to 31 and `.`
- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` - an octet regex (note the non-capturing group, you may use this pattern with `re.findall` in a convenient way to return all matches, no need to iterate the matches with `re.finditer`)
- `(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}` - 3 repetitions of a dot followed with an octet
- `\b` - word boundary

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/gEW2Ig):

```
import re
octet = r'(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
pattern=re.compile(r"\b(?!10\.|192\.168\.|172\.(?:1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\.){0}(?:\.{0}){{3}}\b".format(octet))
text = "10.11.0.0 and here are 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.2 145.12.24.45"
print(pattern.findall(text)) # => ['145.12.24.45']
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches addresses in RFC1918:

```
(^192\.168\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^172\.([1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^10\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)
```

Found here: https://www.regextester.com/95489

To achieve the desired result, simply match all IP's and then remove those that match the ones you want to exclude (staying close to your own example):

```
import re
text='''10.11.0.0', 192.168.1.1, 123.4.5.6'''

pattern=re.compile(r'(\b(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\.(\d|\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-5]{2})\b)')
exclude=re.compile(r'(^192\.168\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^172\.([1][6-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)|(^10\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-2][0-5][0-5])$)')

matches = pattern.finditer(text)
filtered = [match.group() for match in matches if not exclude.match(match.group())]

for match in filtered:
  print(match)
```

Note that you could also use a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension, if you expect the list to be massive, for the same result.